# Django - Pythonic way of extending parent and only changing child class fieldnames?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on some networking-related model mixins and I have two particular models that are supposed to be identical in every way except for their fieldname prefixes.

Picture:

```
class SrcEvent(models.Model):
    src_ip = models.GenericIPField...
    (...many more properties and methods...)

class DstEvent(models.Model):
    dst_ip = models.GenericIPField...
    (...many more properties and methods...)
```

Repeating everything twice (or even just extending one to get the methods on the other) doesn't sit well with me; what I'd like to end up with is a generic abstract class `Event` that just contains attributes like `ip`, `hostname` and such, then extend that with two child classes (`SrcEvent` and `DstEvent`) that append either "src_" or "dst_" to each field when the model is generated/migrated.

I can't just make `Event` and call it a day; some models mix in one, the other, or both sets of attributes, and the direction matters. These models are mixins. The models they get mixed into can have attributes pertaining to a source event (such as an alert), a destination event (such as an email), or both a source and destination event (netflow). So for example a `Netflow(SrcMixin, DstMixin)` model will have both the `src_*` and the `dst_*` sets of fields, which doesn't work if both mixins call their respective IP address field `ip`. This is why I need to maintain the distinction.

I do not know how to go about this within Django, or what to call it to look it up myself. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what "*some models mix in one, the other, or both sets of attributes*" means here?

Comment: Furthermore I do not really understand why you prepend `src_` and `dst_` to the fields. The model itself makes it clear that it is a `DstEvent`, so there is no confusion. In fact using *uniform* attrubtes, makes it easier to calculate common logic (for example printing the `ip` and `port` like `123.45.67.89:100`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem These models are mixins. The models they get mixed into can have attributes pertaining to a source event (such as an alert), a destination event (such as an email), or both a source and destination event (netflow). So for example a `Netflow` model will have both the `src_*` and the `dst_*` sets of fields, which doesn't work if both mixins call their respective IP address field `ip`. This is why I need to maintain the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 'mixin' aspects of this, but it sounds like a case for using an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). with Source(Event) and Destination(Event) classes underneath it.

To define an abstract base class you would use something like:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    #define all your common fields here
```

In the ORM, Source and Destination would become separate tables. As I said, I'm not sure about the 'mixin' aspects, but to a first approximation I think making Source and Destination abstract as well might work, so that objects which instantiate Source or Destination need all the fields populated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working around this through the use of formsets. I leave the fields generic, but I added a new CharField to indicate direction ('src' or 'dst'). Then I create the objects and references to events based on the number of forms submitted and their direction.